# Twilio "click to call" C#

Tags: c#, twilio

Here's my scenario - a user enters his phone number and the number of the person he wants to call.

Via c# Twilio calls the user number then connects to the person he wants to call. I then record the conversation.

I can get it all working and recording for a single phone number.

However, when trying to connect to a second number (the first number does ring, but I get the standard Twilio "application error"), I get the following 502 error:

```
Twilio was unable to fetch content from: https://xxx.xxx.net/Call/Connect?recipientNumber={number}
Error: Error reading response: Response does not contain content type
Account SID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
SID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Request ID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Remote Host: xxx.xxx.net
Request Method: POST
Request URI: https://xxx.xxx.net/Call/Connect?recipientNumber={number}
SSL Version: TLSv1.2
```

This stems from basic code:

```
var response = new VoiceResponse();
response.Say("We are about to connect you.").Dial(recipientNumber).Hangup();
return TwiML(response);
```

Can anyone advise on where I'm going wrong or what I'm missing?

Comment: It might be useful to see a bit more about how you are constructing that response. The error message says that the "response does not contain content type". Are you setting a content type anywhere? It should be set to `application/xml` ideally. Can you make a successful request to your `/Call/Connect` endpoint using curl or postman?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a conflict of versioning and/or DLL's - removed nuget Twilio package and manually added Twilio DLL's. Problem solved!!!